# i have a string variable which comes with function names, how do I call the function in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string variable which comes with different function names, and I have a file which contains an often different set of functions which matchs the content of the string,  how do I call that function in Python?

Example:

In File 1

```
def function1: ...
def function2: ...
def function3: ...
```

In File 2

```
functionname = "function2"
```

I need to call the function2 from the File1 from this file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Function From a String With the Function's Name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

```
myfunction = getattr(mymodule, functionname)
myfunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval("function2")()`

`getattr(<module>, fname)()`

Comment: @Tim Shell is evil as well. `myvar="myowntmpdir"; rm -rf ~/$myvra`. Or python's REPL...

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'function2'

assert re.match('^(?i)[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*$', name)

eval(name)()
```